# Powershell script and Microsoft 365 SharePoint groups

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, microsoft365

I know very little about Powershell and I have been tasked with writing a script that creates microsoft 365 groups in SharePoint with folders added. Can anyone help!

So far, I've been searching for possible Powershell scripts that could work. Howvever, I'm confused with the difference between PnP Powershell and regular Powershell. I'll attach some links to what I found so far; maybe someone could tell me if I'm on the right track.

Comment: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/05/how-to-create-office-365-group-using-powershell.html

Comment: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/08/sharepoint-online-create-folder-using-powershell.html